# What does it mean that cognition is linguistic in itself?

Tags: theoretical-linguistics, philosophy-of-language

Cognition is, generally speaking, ‘linguistic’ in itself, in that it is
the manipulation of language-like structures (propositions) according to formal
rules; (b) the function of natural language is just to express these language-like
structures; therefore, natural language does not affect cognition in any substantial
way.

Comment: Please provide one (or more) references for the claim you mention in your question. It would be helpful to have a paper trail to follow.

Comment: @user2521: In addition to providing references, I think it would be helpful to expand your question a little. For example, do you consider (a) and (b) to contradict or supplement each other?

Comment: It is from Language as a Cognitive Tool
Marco Mirolli • Domenico Parisi

Comment: The statement you quote in the question is so vague that it's difficult to know what the author is arguing for, and i don't have time to read his entire book. What i *can* tell you is that (a) seems to be presupposing the Language of Thought hypothesis advanced by Jerry Fodor. See here: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/language-thought/. The conclusion "that NL does not affect cognition in any substantial way" i would guess is a counter-point to the Sapir-Whorf hypothesis that language affects cognition - see here for details http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/relativism/supplement2.html

Comment: To make things a little more concrete, and to answer your actual question, i would guess that "cognition is linguistic itself" is a reference to the LoT hypothesis mentioned above. To quote the SEP: "The Language of Thought Hypothesis (LOTH) postulates that thought and thinking take place in a mental language. This language consists of a system of representations that is physically realized in the brain of thinkers and has a combinatorial syntax (and semantics) such that operations on representations are causally sensitive only to the syntactic properties of representations". Hope this helps.